# typescript custom component function param throwing warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of code

```
<GoogleLogin
  onSuccess={responseGoogle => {
    const { email, name } = responseGoogle.profileObj; // error: Property 'profileObj' does not exist on type 'GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline'.
  }}
/>
```

The library is here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login

What should I do? I tried (responseGoogle:any) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <GoogleLogin
    onSuccess={(responseGoogle: GoogleLoginResponse ) => {
      const { email, name } = responseGoogle.profileObj

    }}
  />
```

Or you can also use the *as* keyword to let the typescript know that it is of type `GoogleLoginResponse` and not misinterpret it as `GoogleLoginResponseOffline`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the login response type. It can either be `GoogleLoginResponseOffline` or `GoogleLoginResponse`. The property `profileObj` exists only in `GoogleLoginResponse`. If you are requesting offline access, the response will only have a `code` in the response and you should use `GoogleLoginResponseOffline` type.

```
<GoogleLogin
        onSuccess={(responseGoogle: GoogleLoginResponse) => {
          const { email, name } = responseGoogle.profileObj; 

        }}
      />
```

Comment: I got error of `Cannot find name 'GoogleLoginResponse'`

Comment: You need to add `import { GoogleLoginResponse } from 'react-google-login';`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<GoogleLogin
  onSuccess={({ profileObj: { email, name } = {} }: any) => {
    // use email and name
  }
/>
```